# Splash screen api is showing action bar for android 12

Tags: android, kotlin, splash-screen, android-12

After the splash screen loads, I am getting a action bar, but I have set **postSplashScreenTheme** to no action bar theme. This is happening only to android 12 emulator.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/white</item>

        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_icon</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.Design.NoActionBar</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">800</item>

        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: did you find a solution yet? @kunal-kalwar

Comment: Yes @MihodiLushan, now i am calling this **actionBar?.hide()** in my activity in on create.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am calling actionBar?.hide() in onCreate, seems to be working as expected.

```
actionBar?.hide()
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 10):

Add the install function on your launcher activity

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       installSplashScreen()

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

       ...
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen/migrate#migrate_your_splash_screen_implementation

Comment: Worked flawlessly!!

Comment: just a note for someone who is facing this issue and trying this solution, you must call if before setContent{......}

Answer (score 1):

It took me a day to fix this issue. Besides this issue, Android Studio cannot run the application on Android 12 and above. I had to run it manually. I found that the problem is caused by the emulator.

When I tested the application on the real device, I noticed that the AppBar did not appear. But I found another problem. On Android 9 device, SplashScreen doesnt appear, but works perfectly on Android 12 device with implementation **'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-beta02'**.

[image: This white bar shown only Emulator with AndroidVersion >= 12]

Appbar still shown on the emulator but there is no problem on **real device**. Following implementation works both on all Android version.

Note: My app looks like the image above on **Samsung A51**. I'm investigating and trying to find a solution.

**values/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Theme for MainActivity and its fragments -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/black_transparent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/logo_splash</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">200</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBehavior" tools:targetApi="tiramisu">@drawable/logo_splash</item>

        <!-- Set the theme of the Activity that directly follows your splash screen. -->
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**main/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <application
            android:name=".MyApplication"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting">
    
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:exported="true"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".OtherActivity"
                android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
        </application>
</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Load things that should be loaded before rendering MainActivity.
            loadBeforeSplash();
    
            // Handle the splash screen transition.
            splashScreen = SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);
    
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Other MainActivity stuffs
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your splash screen theme if you are using the [Androidx SplashScreen compat library](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/splashscreen/SplashScreen)

```
   <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.App</item>
```

Like:

```
<style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
   <!-- Set the splash screen background, animated icon, and animation duration. -->
   <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/...</item>

   <!-- Use windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon to add either a drawable or an
        animated drawable. One of these is required. -->
   <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/...</item>
   <!-- Required for animated icons -->
   <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">200</item>

   <!-- Set the theme of the Activity that directly follows your splash screen. -->
   <!-- Required -->
   <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.App</item>
</style>
```