How to hide action bar after splash screen in jetpack compose?
I have followed this article Splash screen for below all API levels with icon without any activity. support splash screen for both devices below android 12 and above.
The splash screen works fine in both versions, but after splash screen finish in android 12 the action bar appears although i'm using edgetoEdge(), but it works just fine in a android 5.1.
Here how it appears on device running android 12.

Device running android 5.1.

this is theme.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.SpotifyApp" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
    </style>

</resources>

this theme.xml for V31
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <style name="Theme.SpotifyApp" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/black</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/spotify</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">3000</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.Splash</item>
    </style>
</resources>

Manifest
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@drawable/spotify_icon_small"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/spotify_icon_small"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SpotifyApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.spotify.activities.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.SpotifyApp">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

Theme.kt
@Composable
fun SpotifyTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = false,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }

        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}

MainActivity
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        installSplashScreen()

        setContent {
            SpotifyTheme {
                CompositionLocalProvider(LocalRippleConfiguration provides null) {
                    Surface(modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)){
                        MyAppNavigation()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

tried different solutions i found but still unable to solve it. Note that the splash screen in both device shows correctly without action bar

Try calling installSplashScreen() before calling super.onCreate().

https://stackoverflow.com/q/71584663/15055605

You can achieve this by replacing @style/Theme.Splash on postSplashScreenTheme with your app's theme that has NoActionBar. Here's how you can do it:
<item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.YourApp.NoActionBar</item>

Make sure that Theme.YourAppTheme is defined in your styles.xml with the NoActionBar property. This ensures that after the splash screen, your app transitions smoothly to your main theme without an action bar.

Add dependency
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:<version>"
}

Create composable function for hide the Status Bar
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import com.google.accompanist.systemuicontroller.rememberSystemUiController

@Composable
fun HideStatusBar() {
    val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()

    // Hide the status bar
    systemUiController.isStatusBarVisible = false
  }

Use the function in app
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApp()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    // Hide status bar   
    HideStatusBar()

    // Your content here
    Text(text = "Hello, World!")
}


You can achieve this by replacing @style/Theme.Splash on postSplashScreenTheme with your app's theme that has NoActionBar. Here's how you can do it:
<item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.YourApp.NoActionBar</item>

Make sure that Theme.YourAppTheme is defined in your styles.xml with the NoActionBar property. This ensures that after the splash screen, your app transitions smoothly to your main theme without an action bar.
If that does not work, try to create a new values resource file called for ex: no_action_bar_theme.xml
and just put inside:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.YourApp.NoActionBar" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>

and now you can do this inside your main theme file:
<item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.YourApp.NoActionBar</item>

